# Is there a function like isdate() for datetime2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012, datetime2

I know there is a function called `ISDATE` to validate `DATETIME` columns, but it works only for the `SMALLDATETIME` and `DATETIME` types.

Is there a similar way to validate the new data type `DATETIME2` in SQL Server 2008 and 2012?

Comment: strictly speaking ISDATE() does not validate datetime columns; it validates whether an expression can be parsed as a datetime. After it's in a column it's a bit late!

Comment: @MitchWheat that's a good point. Seems more likely to validate either (a) dates stored incorrectly in a varchar column or (b) input parameters that are of an incorrect data type.

Comment: I'd like to validate input from an excel sheet that has some date columns into a temporary table.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012, you can use `TRY_CONVERT`:

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2012-02-02 13:42:55.2323623'),
       TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME2, '2012-02-31 13:42:55.2323623');
```

Results:

```
2012-02-02 13:42:55.2323623    NULL
```

Or `TRY_PARSE`:

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('2012-02-02 13:42:55.2323623' AS DATETIME2),
       TRY_PARSE('2012-02-31 13:42:55.2323623' AS DATETIME2);
```

(Same results.)

Sorry that I don't have a clever answer for you for < SQL Server 2012. You could, I guess, say

```
SELECT ISDATE(LEFT('2012-02-02 13:42:55.2323623', 23));
```

But that feels dirty.

[`TRY_CONVERT` documentation on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql)
[`TRY_PARSE` documentation on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-parse-transact-sql)

Comment: Clever answer! I liked it very much! Another question about the datetime2 in sql server 2008, is there a way to check for valid date when the value is something like before "January 1, 1753"? Using this command would yeld invalid date SELECT ISDATE(LEFT('2012-02-02 13:42:55.2323623', 23));

Comment: @Vladimir sorry I just noticed your question now. Is it academic or do you really have dates < 1753?

Comment: It's academic. I was wondering how could I validate datetime input when inserting date values into a datetime2 column with something like the isdate() function that works only for the datetime format. The try_contert ant the try_parse functions work only on SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @Vladimir in cases where left(4) < 1754 you could convert to a string, take left 4 as an int, add (19-left(2))*100, then reassemble the string, and that would put your date in the 1900s. You still have some dates to worry about (e.g. September 1753), and leap years won't necessarily align depending on the starting year, but you'd cover most of your bases.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful using the `LEFT(..., 23)` solution on database systems using another dateformat than `mdy` (and SQL-Server 2008). You can see the dateformat of the current session using the [`DBCC USEROPTIONS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-useroptions-transact-sql) command.

On a database system using the german dateformat (`dmy`) the `LEFT(..., 23)` solution isn't working (*detected on dates with day > 12*). See the following test case:

```
-- test table using a DATETIME and DATETIME2 column.
CREATE TABLE dt_vs_dt2 (
  dt DATETIME,
  dt2 DATETIME2
);

-- set a datetime values with a day > 12.
DECLARE @date_value AS DATETIME = DATEADD(DAY, 18 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE());

-- insert the current date into both columns using GETDATE.
-- note: using the following on a day > 12
INSERT INTO dt_vs_dt2 VALUES (@date_value, @date_value);

-- let's have a look at the values.
-- the values look the same (the datetime2 is more precise as expected).
SELECT dt, dt2 FROM dt_vs_dt2;

-- now we expect both values are valid date values.
-- to validate the datetime2 value, the LEFT(..., 23) solution is used.
SELECT ISDATE(dt), ISDATE(LEFT(dt2, 23)) 
FROM dt_vs_dt2;
```

**How to solve that?**

You can use a `CAST(column_name AS DATETIME)` instead of the `LEFT(..., 23)` to make this work:

```
-- using a CAST(... AS DATETIME) instead of `LEFT(..., 23)` seems to work.
SELECT dt, CAST(dt2 AS DATETIME) AS dt2
FROM dt_vs_dt2;

-- now both values are valid dates.
SELECT ISDATE(dt) AS dt, ISDATE(CAST(dt2 AS DATETIME)) AS dt2
FROM dt_vs_dt2;
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk (using `dmy`)**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1c9d1c0c43a34343cf7bd6e5e982f813) / [**demo on dbfiddle.uk (using `mdy`)**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=1e5f7750d5cf57603dcbdfc2a3577398)

---

On SQL Server 2012 and later you should use the `TRY_PARSE` / `TRY_CONVERT` solution described in [@Aaron Bertrand answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11044004/3840840). The `CAST(... AS DATETIME)` solution explained in this answer should also work.