# Iterate over all values in table and check if any value is of type datetime and then change its format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some dynamic columns created inside a SQL Server table, and I want to know which dynamic column has a `datetime` type value.

I got all data in a datatable and then did `select * from datatable;`
but now I don't know how to iterate over every value to know which is of `datetime` type.

Comment: [For the 1024 time – DateTime has no format!](https://zoharpeled.wordpress.com/2019/12/19/for-the-1024-time-datetime-has-no-format/)

Comment: Are you asking which columns have the `datetime` data type?  Or are you asking which columns have string values that look like `datetime`s?  If the latter, provide sample data and desired results.  Also, what is a "dynamic column"?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have the data loaded into the data table you may check if the datatype of the column is date or not via the following command:

```
Select 
isDate(columnName)
from datatable;
```

You can do it on multiple columns as well. The above code is just an example on how to use isDate to check if the column values are date format or not.

Comment: Good suggestion. There is one small caveat with `ISDATE`, as it returns `0` for datetime2 datatype.

Comment: No, `IsDate` checks if a string expression can be converted to a DateTime, it doesn't check the data type of the expression itself.

Comment: @ZoharPeled It checks if it is a valid date and assuming that user wants to check data type based on the values in the column.

Comment: @VenkataramanR Agreed!
This link might be more helpful for datetime2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043981/is-there-a-function-like-isdate-for-datetime2

Comment: @AzherAleem `IsDate` is a problematic suggestion at best, and it also doesn't answer the question being asked here. First, it doesn't say anything about the actual data type (which is what the OP asked for), second, it's non-deterministic (most of the times), third, it doesn't play well with the more modern data type of `datetime2`, and for many more reasons (read [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

Comment: @ZoharPeled Agreed for datetime2 datatype. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can use system catalog to find out the types.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test(a int, b datetime)

SELECT c.name,ty.name 
FROM sys.columns as c
join sys.tables as t
on c.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.types as ty
on ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
where t.name = 'test'
```

```
+------+----------+
| name |   name   |
+------+----------+
| a    | int      |
| b    | datetime |
+------+----------+
```